# Firebase orderByValue().equalTo() is not a function (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database has the following structure:

```
"groupA" : {
  "applications" : {
    "applicationID_132" : {
      "status" : "accepted"
    },
    "applicationID_423" : {
      "status" : "declined"
    },
    "applicationID_562" : {
      "status" : "accepted"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the snapshot of applications with "accepted" status (to be able to skip fetching all applications) by:

```
return admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').orderByValue('status').equalTo('accepted')
                  .once('value')
                  .then(acceptedApplicationsSnapshot => {
```

Doesn't seem to work, tried orderBy and orderByValue as well. What might be missing or what is the better way to handle this case?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: you can't pass parameter to `orderByValue` check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `child.orderByChild().value()`

In your case:

```
return admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').orderByChild('status').equalTo('accepted')
                  .once('value')
                  .then(acceptedApplicationsSnapshot => {
```

---

**You could use `orderByValue()` as well**, but first you would need to get the Reference which you want to order - function does not accept parameter.

#### How to use orderByValue()?

`.child(..)` returns a Reference in your case that is `applications` if you want to use `orderByValue` than you would need to get reference to 'status' before doing that, eg:

`admin.database().ref('groupA').child('applications').child('status').orderByValue()` and then you would apply one of the data [filtering methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) eg.
`.equalTo('accepted')...`

Comment: thank you! there's a typo in my question, "tried orderByChild* as well," same result

Comment: If it’s throwing error can you share the stack trace

Comment: I have just tried this (`orderByChild`) and it works. using `orderByValue('...')` will throw an error: `Error: Query.orderByValue failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects none.`